# Android Video Recording ,Camera Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I use following `Intent`s for recording video and taking pictures, but in Motorola Droid 2.2 the camera `Intent` save option fails, ie nothing get saved, and the camcoder `Intent` cancel crashes my application.

In both `Intent` I explicitly passing the file and after it return result "ok" I use the file, ie when user press the save/insert options in the intent: SAVE in camcoder no problem, only cancel casues crash in camcorder.

Camera

```
 Intent intent2 = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
 imgUri = Uri.fromFile(photofile);
 intent2.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imgUri);
 startActivityForResult(intent2, 1);
```

Camcoder

```
 Intent i = new Intent("android.media.action.VIDEO_CAPTURE");
 i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(videofile));
 i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
 i.putExtra("android.intent.extra.durationLimit", 60);
 startActivityForResult(i, 2);
```

NB: The Recorded Video can't be played with HTC ERIS

Comment: i.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 0);
change the video quality.

Comment: you need to provide crash logs from Logcat

Answer (score 1):

If you can't avoid using `android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` try to prepare URI via content provider like that

```
context.getContentResolver().insert(android.provider.MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);
```

To to so you should prepare correct content values first (setup MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE and so on).

But the best way is just to not specify you own URI and user URI that system will give for your video.